# S3 MalformedXML error randomly occuring when uploading using multipart upload

Tags: java, amazon-s3

I am trying to upload zip files to s3 using multipart upload and I am randomly seeing the below S3 Exception and the upload fails. "The XML you provided was not well-formed or did not validate against our published schema"

The file upload error is seen randomly once for every 10 uploads (I am unable to trace any pattern).

Can anyone please suggest why this issue can happen and any possible fixes? Thanks!
Using - AWS SDK for Java 2.x

Full error logs:

```
software.amazon.awssdk.services.s3.model.S3Exception: The XML you provided was not well-formed or did not validate against our published schema (Service: S3, Status Code: 400, Request ID: EHPZM8JE3YZSB0XH, Extended Request ID: vomj6L9xM0weSVI3CWurMWWEOIaIYDRuj6ah/ZHHNkt7eZwH626bfbjKYOIS8A9ONZ3mChHS0+M=)
    at software.amazon.awssdk.protocols.xml.internal.unmarshall.AwsXmlPredicatedResponseHandler.handleErrorResponse(AwsXmlPredicatedResponseHandler.java:156) ~[aws-xml-protocol-2.17.242.jar:?]
    at software.amazon.awssdk.protocols.xml.internal.unmarshall.AwsXmlPredicatedResponseHandler.handleResponse(AwsXmlPredicatedResponseHandler.java:108) ~[aws-xml-protocol-2.17.242.jar:?]
    at software.amazon.awssdk.protocols.xml.internal.unmarshall.AwsXmlPredicatedResponseHandler.handle(AwsXmlPredicatedResponseHandler.java:85) ~[aws-xml-protocol-2.17.242.jar:?]
    at software.amazon.awssdk.protocols.xml.internal.unmarshall.AwsXmlPredicatedResponseHandler.handle(AwsXmlPredicatedResponseHandler.java:43) ~[aws-xml-protocol-2.17.242.jar:?]
    at software.amazon.awssdk.awscore.client.handler.AwsSyncClientHandler$Crc32ValidationResponseHandler.handle(AwsSyncClientHandler.java:95) ~[aws-core-2.17.242.jar:?]
    at software.amazon.awssdk.core.internal.handler.BaseClientHandler.lambda$successTransformationResponseHandler$7(BaseClientHandler.java:245) ~[sdk-core-2.17.242.jar:?]
    at software.amazon.awssdk.core.internal.http.pipeline.stages.HandleResponseStage.execute(HandleResponseStage.java:40) ~[sdk-core-2.17.242.jar:?]
    at software.amazon.awssdk.core.internal.http.pipeline.stages.HandleResponseStage.execute(HandleResponseStage.java:30) ~[sdk-core-2.17.242.jar:?]
    at software.amazon.awssdk.core.internal.http.pipeline.RequestPipelineBuilder$ComposingRequestPipelineStage.execute(RequestPipelineBuilder.java:206) ~[sdk-core-2.17.242.jar:?]
    at software.amazon.awssdk.core.internal.http.pipeline.stages.ApiCallAttemptTimeoutTrackingStage.execute(ApiCallAttemptTimeoutTrackingStage.java:73) ~[sdk-core-2.17.242.jar:?]
    at software.amazon.awssdk.core.internal.http.pipeline.stages.ApiCallAttemptTimeoutTrackingStage.execute(ApiCallAttemptTimeoutTrackingStage.java:42) ~[sdk-core-2.17.242.jar:?]
    at software.amazon.awssdk.core.internal.http.pipeline.stages.TimeoutExceptionHandlingStage.execute(TimeoutExceptionHandlingStage.java:78) ~[sdk-core-2.17.242.jar:?]
    at software.amazon.awssdk.core.internal.http.pipeline.stages.TimeoutExceptionHandlingStage.execute(TimeoutExceptionHandlingStage.java:40) ~[sdk-core-2.17.242.jar:?]
    at software.amazon.awssdk.core.internal.http.pipeline.stages.ApiCallAttemptMetricCollectionStage.execute(ApiCallAttemptMetricCollectionStage.java:50) ~[sdk-core-2.17.242.jar:?]
    at software.amazon.awssdk.core.internal.http.pipeline.stages.ApiCallAttemptMetricCollectionStage.execute(ApiCallAttemptMetricCollectionStage.java:36) ~[sdk-core-2.17.242.jar:?]
    at software.amazon.awssdk.core.internal.http.pipeline.stages.RetryableStage.execute(RetryableStage.java:81) ~[sdk-core-2.17.242.jar:?]
    at software.amazon.awssdk.core.internal.http.pipeline.stages.RetryableStage.execute(RetryableStage.java:36) ~[sdk-core-2.17.242.jar:?]
    at software.amazon.awssdk.core.internal.http.pipeline.RequestPipelineBuilder$ComposingRequestPipelineStage.execute(RequestPipelineBuilder.java:206) ~[sdk-core-2.17.242.jar:?]
    at software.amazon.awssdk.core.internal.http.StreamManagingStage.execute(StreamManagingStage.java:56) ~[sdk-core-2.17.242.jar:?]
    at software.amazon.awssdk.core.internal.http.StreamManagingStage.execute(StreamManagingStage.java:36) ~[sdk-core-2.17.242.jar:?]
    at software.amazon.awssdk.core.internal.http.pipeline.stages.ApiCallTimeoutTrackingStage.executeWithTimer(ApiCallTimeoutTrackingStage.java:80) ~[sdk-core-2.17.242.jar:?]
    at software.amazon.awssdk.core.internal.http.pipeline.stages.ApiCallTimeoutTrackingStage.execute(ApiCallTimeoutTrackingStage.java:60) ~[sdk-core-2.17.242.jar:?]
    at software.amazon.awssdk.core.internal.http.pipeline.stages.ApiCallTimeoutTrackingStage.execute(ApiCallTimeoutTrackingStage.java:42) ~[sdk-core-2.17.242.jar:?]
    at software.amazon.awssdk.core.internal.http.pipeline.stages.ApiCallMetricCollectionStage.execute(ApiCallMetricCollectionStage.java:48) ~[sdk-core-2.17.242.jar:?]
    at software.amazon.awssdk.core.internal.http.pipeline.stages.ApiCallMetricCollectionStage.execute(ApiCallMetricCollectionStage.java:31) ~[sdk-core-2.17.242.jar:?]
    at software.amazon.awssdk.core.internal.http.pipeline.RequestPipelineBuilder$ComposingRequestPipelineStage.execute(RequestPipelineBuilder.java:206) ~[sdk-core-2.17.242.jar:?]
    at software.amazon.awssdk.core.internal.http.pipeline.RequestPipelineBuilder$ComposingRequestPipelineStage.execute(RequestPipelineBuilder.java:206) ~[sdk-core-2.17.242.jar:?]
    at software.amazon.awssdk.core.internal.http.pipeline.stages.ExecutionFailureExceptionReportingStage.execute(ExecutionFailureExceptionReportingStage.java:37) ~[sdk-core-2.17.242.jar:?]
    at software.amazon.awssdk.core.internal.http.pipeline.stages.ExecutionFailureExceptionReportingStage.execute(ExecutionFailureExceptionReportingStage.java:26) ~[sdk-core-2.17.242.jar:?]
    at software.amazon.awssdk.core.internal.http.AmazonSyncHttpClient$RequestExecutionBuilderImpl.execute(AmazonSyncHttpClient.java:193) ~[sdk-core-2.17.242.jar:?]
    at software.amazon.awssdk.core.internal.handler.BaseSyncClientHandler.invoke(BaseSyncClientHandler.java:103) ~[sdk-core-2.17.242.jar:?]
    at software.amazon.awssdk.core.internal.handler.BaseSyncClientHandler.doExecute(BaseSyncClientHandler.java:167) ~[sdk-core-2.17.242.jar:?]
    at software.amazon.awssdk.core.internal.handler.BaseSyncClientHandler.lambda$execute$1(BaseSyncClientHandler.java:82) ~[sdk-core-2.17.242.jar:?]
    at software.amazon.awssdk.core.internal.handler.BaseSyncClientHandler.measureApiCallSuccess(BaseSyncClientHandler.java:175) ~[sdk-core-2.17.242.jar:?]
    at software.amazon.awssdk.core.internal.handler.BaseSyncClientHandler.execute(BaseSyncClientHandler.java:76) ~[sdk-core-2.17.242.jar:?]
    at software.amazon.awssdk.core.client.handler.SdkSyncClientHandler.execute(SdkSyncClientHandler.java:45) ~[sdk-core-2.17.242.jar:?]
    at software.amazon.awssdk.awscore.client.handler.AwsSyncClientHandler.execute(AwsSyncClientHandler.java:56) ~[aws-core-2.17.242.jar:?]
    at software.amazon.awssdk.services.s3.DefaultS3Client.completeMultipartUpload(DefaultS3Client.java:637) ~[s3-2.17.242.jar:?]
```